# What's the area of the region $F$ in this diagram?

Tags: geometry

I have exams coming up. So I would appreciate your help a lot.

The region named "$F$" is defined in the diagram below. With Pythagoras, I found out that $AB$ is 8 cm and $IG$ is 5cm. I also thought about splitting $F$ into a triangle and a rectangle. Can anyone please help me to solve this task?

[image: find the size of F in square centimeters]

Comment: Your measurements of $AB$ and $IG$ are wrong. 
$$2^2+4^2=(\text{length of }IG)^2\implies \text{length of }IG=\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt{5}$$
and
$$(4+2)^2+(4+2)^2=(\text{length of }AB)^2\implies \text{length of }AB=\sqrt{72}=6\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: okay thank you. do you have any idea what to do then to find F?? please would be great

Comment: Is that semicircle-with-a-point-in-it angle notation supposed to mean it is a straight angle ($\,90^\circ\,$)? Did you notice the quadrilateral whose area is F is a trapezoid?

Comment: yes i saw that it´trapezoid. but found it´s more hard this way...

Comment: I'm not so sure about that: after all, you still need to know the areas of those little triangles and except the upper one, for the other you still have to calculate their legs' lengths, which is exactly what I did to calculate directly the trapezoid's area, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you want the **area** of the shaded region. The whole big triangle has area $(1/2)(6)(6)$.

Now find the areas of the *unshaded* bits, and subtract from the whole.

The area of the top unshaded triangle is very easy. Now let's work on the area of the unshaded triangle on the left. It is an isosceles right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $4$. The *nice* way to find its area is to observe that $4$ copies of it can be put together to make a $4\times 4$ square. Or else you can find the legs using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Thank you. Can I assume that the two small unshaded triangles at the bottom are isosceles? Because I have only the size of one side of them. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to assume it, you can **prove** it. The big triangle is right-angled and certainly isosceles, its legs are both $6$. The big triangle has a right angle and is isosceles, so its two other angles are $45^\circ$. That gives you what you want. Or else note that for example the little triangle on the left is **similar** to the big one.  Same applies to the little triangle on the right.

Comment: thank you very much. i really enjoyed your help!

Comment: comes to 9 square centimeters at the end :-)

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, it is $9$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The area of the region $F$ is the area of the whole triangle $\triangle ABC$, minus the areas of the three non-shaded triangles.

Comment: Thank you. Can I assume that the two small unshaded triangles at the bottom are isosceles? Because I have only the size of one side of them. Thanks!

Comment: You can; because you have several angles that are right angles, and because you know that the big triangle is an isoceles right triangle, you can show that the bottom two triangles will also have to be isoceles right triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Call $\,M,N\,$ resp. the two points where those perpendiculars from $\,I,G\,$ intersect $\,AB\,$ .Since all the triangles in the diagram are straight-angled and isosceles (why?) , we have that

$$MI=AM=\frac{AI}{\sqrt 2}=2\sqrt 2\;\;,\;\;NG=NB=\frac{GN}{\sqrt 2}=\sqrt 2$$

Thus, the basis of the trapezoid $\,MNIG\,$ are $\,MI, NG\,$ , and its height is

$$h=AB-AM-NB=6\sqrt 2-2\sqrt 2-\sqrt 2=3\sqrt 2$$

so

$$F=A_{MNIG}=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2\right)3\sqrt 2=\frac{18}{2}=9$$

Comment: okay thanks for that solution too :-)

Comment: @Sophia,  it is expected in this site (1) from posters (and anyone, in fact) to upvote questions that they like, that they find helpful and/or interesting, and (2) from the posters *to choose* as "accepted answer" the best one in their opinion (they can take their time to do this, though).